# Variable value for Amount for Salesforce opportunity API

Tags: salesforce, magento2, salesforce-lightning

I'm working on a Magento website. In that, after the customer is done with adding products to the cart he fills a form and once the form is submitted, form data along with product details like SKU, price is sent to Salesforce to create a new opportunity.

The API is working and the Data is going to salesforce, but the issue is that the same product can have different prices based on certain conditions.

the new amount going to salesforce but on the salesforce side, the new amount is not reflecting but the amount when the product is created for the first time is coming.

is there any way to make the amount a variable field so the new amount reflects?

below is an image of the opportunity and the JSON data I'm sending.

[image]

`{"StageName":"New Opportunity","Name":"test","CloseDate":"2021-06-04","What_are_you_interested_in__c":"Purchase New Trailer","Product_JSON__c":"[{\"Name\":\"Large Trailers\",\"Sku\":\"large-trailers-rent\",\"Quantity\":1,\"Price\":\"1301.0400\"}]","Purchase_Delivery_Contact_Phone__c":"123","On_Site_Contact_Email__c":"test-12@test-12.com","Mailing_Street__c":"test-12","Delivery_Street__c":"","Qty__c":"1","X66969__c":0,"First_Name__c":"test-12","Last_Name__c":"test-12"}`

Answer (score 1):

This request looks weird. Vanilla Salesforce doesn't need hacks like a text field to hold serialised JSON in it (`Product_JSON__c`).

Where do you send it? Normal `POST` to something like `services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Opportunity` or some custom endpoint (it'd have "/apexrest" in the URL). Even if it goes to normal endpoint - I guess there's trigger that deserialises this `Product_JSON__c` and creates OpportunityLineItems out of it. You'll have to chat with developer responsible for that trigger, we can't tell what's going on in there.

In general yes, it's possible to have variable prices. You (or that developer) have to read up about [`OpportunityLineItem`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm). There's `ListPrice,UnitPrice,TotalPrice,Discount`, lots of choices to do this right and report properly on the discounts! And there are tips like

> Creating an OpportunityLineItem increments the Opportunity Amount
> value by the TotalPrice of the OpportunityLineItem

There are ways to do it properly, insert header (Opportunity) and line items in one go, without such hacks. See

- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155422/using-the-rest-api-to-create-parent-and-child-records-in-a-single-http-request
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274694/can-you-upsert-using-composite-sobject-tree
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm